# Dynamic HTML Construction

Tags: html, templates, dynamic, reusability, consistency

Every time I decide to change something in my header/navigationbar/footer/etc. I need to apply those changes to 16 other html files so my changes are consistent across my entire website.

My question is: is there a way i can make my website's template be automatically applied to every page?

An example of any page on my website and what i have in mind would look like this:

```
<html>
    <head>injected code</head>
    <body>
        <header>injected code<header>
        <section>NOT INJECTED CODE</section>
        <footer>injected code</footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

I know repeating code like this is bad practice, so how do i reuse (localize) code for these areas of my html since they will always be the same?

I am not really interested in content management systems.

Comment: What backend do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i do with the elements that are the same on every page, like the header, nav, footer is create those elements in a file apart and then include via php. Then if you have to change one thing in the header you only have to do it one time.

Your example will be like:

```
<body>
   <header><?php include_once('header.html'); ?><header>
   <section>NOT INJECTED CODE</section>
   <footer><?php include_once('footer.html'); ?></footer>
</body>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks, this helps a lot! also thanks to the other guy who answered and provided the xampp development environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use php to solve this. Name your file "index.php" (or anything else with .php as the extension)

```
<html>
 <?php include('header.php'); ?>
<body>
    <header>injected code<header>
    <section>NOT INJECTED CODE</section>
    <footer>injected code</footer>
</body>
<?php include('footer.php'); ?>
```

Then make header.php and footer.php in the same folder. These common files can then be included in all your pages.

Tip: You will need to run these on a local server. See [xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

The best way that I can think of would be to use a server side language, such as php or asp , to generate the html.
You can use `<iframe>` tag to include external file however I have not properly tried this and am not sure of the security or results. 
You can also use javascript/jquery to write to the document, however using scripts just to write would not be best practice, a better use for client-side language would be to use `ajax` to load external files however some of the header may need to be defined before the ajax is complete although I haven't tested it.

In short I would recommend using a server side language probably php as it is  easy to learn, free to use and you can install it on your local machine. If you already have a server running you can see what languages are already installed as most languages can include external files.